# Gstreamer udp server

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

**Client 1** $ gstreamer1.0 v4l2src ! ... ! udpsink host=server-ip

**Server** $ gstreamer1.0 udpsrc ! ***udpsink ????***

**Client 2** $ gstreamer udpsrc url=udp://server-ip ! ... ! xvimagesink

Notes :

- Client 1, 2 and server on different networks.
- Client 1 and 2 has dynamic IP.
- Server has static IP.

How to create "udp video streaming" server ?

Comment: What? What class is this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP can't send data to dynamic IP.

You can use ***TCP*** instead.

[Gstreamer 1.0 TCP](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-plugin-tcp.html)